# cmd executescalar is not returning a value for my idnumber (identity) on my messagebox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Every time I add a new employee in my program using the code below, I don't get the `ID NUMBER` in the messagebox. The code just returns a value of `0` every time I add, but in the database it still increments the `id` number.

Here's my code:

```
Dim add As String = String.Empty
    add &= "insert into record (firstname, middlename, lastname, birthday, age, department) "
    add &= "values "
    add &= "(@fn, @mn, @ln, @bd, @age, @dept)"

    If afn.Text.Length < 2 Then
        MsgBox("Please input More value on Firstname")
    ElseIf amn.Text.Length < 2 Then
        MsgBox("Please input more value on Middlename")
    ElseIf aln.Text.Length < 2 Then
        MsgBox("Please input more value on Lastname")
    ElseIf abday.Text > "2000-01-01" Then
        MsgBox("Birthday is not appropriate")
    ElseIf adept.SelectedItem = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please select a Department")
    Else

        Using conn As New SqlConnection("server=WIN10;database=hrdept;user=elix;password=blackant;")
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand
                With cmd
                    .Connection = conn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = add
                    .Parameters.Add("@fn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = afn.Text
                    .Parameters.Add("@mn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = amn.Text
                    .Parameters.Add("@ln", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = aln.Text
                    .Parameters.Add("@bd", SqlDbType.Date).Value = abday.Text
                    .Parameters.Add("@age", SqlDbType.Int).Value = aage.Value
                    .Parameters.Add("@dept", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = adept.SelectedItem
                End With

                Try
                    conn.Open()
                    Dim id As Integer = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
                    If aage.Value < 20 Then

                        If MsgBox("Age must be 20 years old and above is this an INTERN?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

                            MsgBox("NEW EMPLOYEE ADDED" & Environment.NewLine &
                                   "ID NUMBER: " & id & Environment.NewLine &
                                   "First Name: " & afn.Text & Environment.NewLine &
                                   "Middle Name: " & amn.Text & Environment.NewLine &
                                   "Last Name: " & aln.Text & Environment.NewLine &
                                   "Birthday: " & abday.Text & Environment.NewLine &
                                   "Age: " & aage.Value & Environment.NewLine &
                                   "Department: " & adept.SelectedItem & Environment.NewLine
                                   )
                        ElseIf MsgBoxResult.No Then
                            MsgBox("Action cancelled")
                        End If
                    Else

                        MsgBox("NEW EMPLOYEE ADDED" & Environment.NewLine &
                               "ID NUMBER: " & id & Environment.NewLine &
                               "First Name: " & afn.Text & Environment.NewLine &
                               "Middle Name: " & amn.Text & Environment.NewLine &
                               "Last Name: " & aln.Text & Environment.NewLine &
                               "Birthday: " & abday.Text & Environment.NewLine &
                               "Age: " & aage.Value & Environment.NewLine &
                               "Department: " & adept.SelectedItem & Environment.NewLine
                               )
                    End If

                    conn.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try

            End Using
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your query like:

```
insert into record (firstname,middlename,lastname,birthday,age,department) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID values ....
```

`INSERTED` is an in-build object of your row type.
`ID` is your `ID` column, rename this if it's some thing else.
Similarly, you can also add more column to output like `INSERTED.firstname`

Answer (score 0):

Add a semicolon at the end of your Insert statement. Then add this to the string after the semicolon

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

there shouldn't be any other changes to your code needed.